# Remove spaces and number in lines till first character in a line

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

I have a file `test_file` like below in `Linux`.

```
ags;'s


dkfprper


sdkl;d;;'s

ip access

 100 200 remark
 50 deny pdldsl;l;sd;;l;d
 permit eyuopopqwopq
 10 permit eteioe
 200 200 200 deny abc

remark aiii[dsigdfidflkfk

1 deny
```

Now I want to extract the lines that contains `ip or remark or deny or permit` in them

I have done like below.

```
grep -E 'ip|remark|deny|permit' test_file >> string_check
```

The result is below

```
ip access
 100 200 remark
 50 deny pdldsl;l;sd;;l;d
 permit eyuopopqwopq
 10 permit eteioe
 200 200 200 deny abc
remark aiii[dsigdfidflkfk
1 deny
```

Now from this I want to remove all the `numbers and spaces` from the lines till I get `ip or remark or deny or permit` as starting words.

The result I want is

```
ip access
remark
deny pdldsl;l;sd;;l;d
permit eyuopopqwopq
permit eteioe
deny abc
remark aiii[dsigdfidflkfk
deny
```

I have done like below but i am not getting any result

```
sed 's/^ *//g' string_check
```

This removes only the spaces at the start of a line

How can I achieve my result?

Comment: You were close `sed 's/^[ 0-9]*//' string_check`. (though David's answer below combining all operations saves spawning 2 additional subshells)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed -E -n 's/^[ 0-9]*(ip|remark|deny|permit)/\1/p' test_file
```

Breaking this down:

- `sed -E` says to use "extend" regexp syntax; without it you would need many more backslashes
- `sed -n` says to not print out lines, unless a `p` command is used
- The regular expression matches spaces or digits at the start of the line followed by one of the keywords
- The replacement replaces this string at the start of the line with only the keyword
- `s///p` says to print out the line if a replacement was done